# Force JasperReports Server scheduler (quartz) to recalculate next run time

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler, jasperserver

To get a bunch of new reports to run I changed the system date on my *JasperReports Server*. After I changed it back, the normally-scheduled reports did not run because the "next run time" is evidently calculated statically based on the previous run.

How can I force the quartz scheduler to recalculate the next run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing: **for each scheduled report**, edit the scheduled report and change the execution time by some small amount (say a minute). Then, click Next Next Next until you are done editing. This apparently forces the scheduler to recalculate; however, it is horribly time-consuming! If you do not change the execution time it will not recalculate the next run time.

Good luck.